# Javascript get correct Number from numbers in card stack

Tags: javascript, poker

I'm calling `getNumber` with a number from 1 -51 in a card stack, that is representing a card.

But I'm seeing a lot of `getNumber` results in getting 0 and 1 as value.

For example, card with number 13 would return 0 in getNumber function. while `39` would be 0 .

The 13 would ideally return 13.

How can I make so the getNumber from 1-52 would result in getting the correct value represented? where 14 would be A ( aka 14), and King (13) ?

My code:

```
 function numbers() { return  ["2","3","4","5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"]; }


function suits() { return ["h", "s", "d", "c"]; }

function getSuit(card) {
    return (Math.floor(card / 13));
}
function getNumber(card)
{

    return card - (getSuit(card) * 13);
}
```

Comment: What is `function numbers()` is for if you never call it?
What do you actually try to achieve?

Comment: i call function numbers if the number is a string and im not dealing with 1-52.

Comment: Could you give an example of input you're sending and output you want to get?

Comment: I do not understand what input should have what output. Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: You realize there's already a mod (%) operator, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the shortform of a card deck like 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,B,D,K,A :

```
function getNumber(n){
 n=(n-1)%12;
 return ["B","D","K","A"][n-8] || (n+2)+"";
}

for(var i=1;i<=52;i++) console.log(getNumber(i));
```

http://jsbin.com/wilifevaga/edit?console